# Ignore InProcServer32 registry entry for Midas.dll

Tags: delphi, registry, tclientdataset

Recently we installed our program which uses Midas.dll for a new customer. Unfortunately this customer's laptop has an invalid registry entry for the Midas.dll location (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{9E8D2FA1-591C-11D0-BF52-0020AF32BD64}\InProcServer32`) - or maybe the entry is only *sometimes* valid, e.g. when the laptop is docked. Our customer support doesn't want to mess with the customer's registry.

So is there a way to make our app ignore this entry and just use our local copy of the DLL?

FWIW: I found [MidasLib.dcu makes the application slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449386/midaslib-dcu-makes-the-application-slower) but the solution there seems to be to programmatically adapt the registry to our needs which I want to avoid.

Comment: Windows implementation of `Datasnap.DSIntf.CheckDbClient` calls `System.Win.ComObj.RegisterComServer` with Midas.dll file path obtained from registry. Is hooking this procedure (`RegisterComServer`) an option?

Comment: Oh .. wait. It is only called when Midas is *not* registered. Then hooking `LoadLibrary` could do the trick.

Comment: Won't hooking `LoadLibrary` conjure up malware detection and so on?

Comment: What about using Registration-free COM to bypass the Registry altogether?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The `CheckDbClient` routine contains an explicit call to `RegQueryValue`. Can I bypass this by registration-free COM?

Answer (score 1):

```
uses MidasLib;
```

Use this module first. It will initialize static registration.